# adding multiple listbox items into one listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm using vb.net form.

I have 8 listboxes (listbox1 , listbox2,listbox3..) each one contains many items  and another empty listbox (listbox10). I'm trying to add first listboxes items into the listbox10

ex: ) listbox1 first items is 'A' , listbox2 first items is 'b' , listbox3 first items is 'c'...etc . Now listbox10 first item must be "Abc..."

The problem is i'm only able to add 3 listboxes into the listbox10 
But i want to all 8 listboxes to include in the loop.

here is my code

```
Dim n As Integer = _
Math.Min(ListBox1.Items.Count, Math.Min(ListBox2.Items.Count,    ListBox3.Items.Count))

For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
ListBox10.Items.Add( _
    ListBox1.Items(i).ToString + _
    ListBox2.Items(i).ToString + _
    ListBox3.Items(i).ToString)
Next
```

Comment: Looking at your Math.Min expression I presume that your listboxes contain a different quantity of items. Right?

Comment: @Steve no all of them with same quantity items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `List<Listbox>` of all the listboxes that you want to work on. 
Then, using Linq, is pretty easy to reach your objective

```
Dim controls = new List(Of Listbox)() From _
      { listbox1, listbox2, listbox3, ....etc.... }
Dim minCount = controls.Min(Function(x) x.Items.Count)
for x = 0 to minCount-1
    listbox10.Items.Add(string.Join(" ", controls.Select(Function(lb) lb.Items(x).ToString)))
Next
```

Of course, if all the Listbox have the same amount of items then the calculation to find the listbox with the lower amount of items is useless, you could replace it using the Items.Count of any Listbox (However, in defensive programming, I would leave it)

Comment: Thanks for the kind support, but alot of errors occur when trying above code

Comment: Sorry, this is C#, I will fix the answer for Vb.NET

Comment: Don't worry at all :)

Comment: All right, that should be working as well for VB.NET (Do not forget to Imports System.Linq )

Comment: So much appreciate your help .. but im trying to add the refrence linq .. but cant find it at all .. ill keep trying .. many thanks

Comment: No need to add a reference, instead you should add Imports System.Linq to the top of your files.

Comment: I add it but a break shown up with refrence to this line :  ListBox13.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", controls.Select(Function(lb) lb.Items(x).ToString)))

Comment: here is warning that show up : ( Warning Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable.

Comment: May i ask you about one little detail? .. or i'm causing you enough headache?

Comment: I am sorry but I am at work now and cannot give much time here. Please add a new question